# Redirect a site to SSL using IIS/rewrite module

Tags: regex, web-config, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

Im trying to redirect all urls of a site to SSL using IIS/rewrite module.

I have this rule which works fine for all urls except ones that contain a virtual directory/application called 'blog'

```
 <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

So redirecting www.example.com/blog/post/test to https doesn't work, but www.example.com/pages/demo does.

And for some reason www.example.com/blog redirects but www.example.com/blog/ does not.

If someone could point me in the right direction please. I hate this rewrite/regex stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force HTTP to HTTPS for a particular site on all URLs and hate Regex then

- Simply create a URL Rewrite rule on site.
- Use wildcard type as they are little easy to understand.

This should work for HTTP to https

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Normally when I am playing with urlrewrite / redirection I use redirect type "temporary" so that browser doesn't cache the HTTP to HTTPS rule. Once I finish my testing I change redirect type to permanent.

Comment: Thanks, but no difference. Im sure that it has to do with the blog virtual directory. Any url with /blog/ isn't matched at all. The blog is a web application with a web.config but there's no rules in it. I've clicked on "Revert to parent" in IIS